# Wordpress query portfolio posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

On my template I have this code

```
<div class="blog_block">

    <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
    <?php $nbmax= 9; ?>
    <?php $tarali_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page='.$nbmax.'&ignore_sticky_posts=1&paged='.$paged); ?>
    <?php while ($tarali_query -> have_posts()) : $tarali_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-blog', get_post_format() );   ?>                                              
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php tarali_paging_nav(); ?>   

</div><!-- blog_block -->
```

Which render **ALL** recent posts of my blog. How can I modify this code to query ONLY the posts which belongs to **Portfolio Category**?

Comment: Please review the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply just add the `cat` or `category_name` parameter to your query. When using `cat`, you should use the **category ID**, and should you use `category_name`, it should be the **slug** of the category, not the name.

Change

```
<?php $tarali_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page='.$nbmax.'&ignore_sticky_posts=1&paged='.$paged); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $tarali_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page='.$nbmax.'&cat=CATID&ignore_sticky_posts=1&paged='.$paged); ?>
```

For futher reading: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I did exactly as you said I changed the code to this
<?php $tarali_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page='.$nbmax.'&cat=porto&ignore_sticky_posts=1&paged='.$paged); ?>
but nothing has changed at all.

Comment: `cat` should be a numerical value

Comment: If porto is the slug, change `cat` to `category_name`

Comment: I did that now there is no posts at all

Comment: Paste your code please

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you a lot your solution is correct. I tried another category and it worked just fine. sorry for delay I had internet cut off

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted. Enjoy :)